# AttributeError: 'torch.return_types.max' object has no attribute 'dim' - Maxpooling Channel

Tags: python, computer-vision, pytorch

I'm trying to do maxpooling over channel dimension:

```
class ChannelPool(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, input):
        return torch.max(input, dim=1)
```

but I get the error

```
AttributeError: 'torch.return_types.max' object has no attribute 'dim'
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [`torch.max`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.max.html#torch.max) function called with `dim` returns a tuple so:

```
class ChannelPool(nn.Module):
    def forward(self, input):
        input_max, max_indices = torch.max(input, dim=1)
        return input_max
```

From the [documentation of torch.max](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.max.html#torch.max):

> Returns a namedtuple (values, indices) where values is the maximum value of each row of the input tensor in the given dimension dim. And indices is the index location of each maximum value found (argmax).

Answer (score 9):

I met the same err recently. There are 2 form of [torch.max()](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.max).

- if you just give a input tensor (without other args like `dim` ...), max() function will return a tensor
- if you specify other args (for example `dim=0`), max() function will returns a namedtuple: (values, indices). I guess the `values` is what you want.

Comment: Specifically, `torch.max(input, dim=1).values` in the context of the OP's question.